# Reference to Event object in javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

code below works fine if I run it on google chrome browser but it doesn't on firefox

the event object is undefined in firefox .So how can I get a reference to event object in this case

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>

<button onclick="displayDate()">The time is?</button>

<script>
function displayDate(e) {
if (!e) var e = window.event;
alert(e.target.innerText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox, you have to pass the event to the function:

```
<button onclick="displayDate(event)">The time is?</button>

<script>
  function displayDate(e) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
  }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k6cge4a0/1/